# Is it possible to update the plot output that's displayed on a separate tab?

Tags: r, shiny

My friend and I are making a shiny app where you can upload data and by clicking a button create a tab where a plot is rendered using that data. We want to dynamically make as many tabs as we want and then when we filter the data using the selectInput on the tab we're currently on, render a plot(overwrite the one on the current tab) based on the changes that have been made. Is there an example we can follow and possibly use to get our script to work?

Comment: Please use more direct/objective questions -- better questions get better answers. This question is probably translated to "Using dynamically created tabs, how to render/plot elements based on currently selected tab outside of the tab usual content?"

Answer (score 1):

Following https://mastering-shiny.org/action-layout.html#multi-page-layouts

Using standard `tabsetPanel` and associated `input` variable, it is possible to draw/plot accordingly to selected tab, even out side the tab. See example below (from referenced page).

Note that the `tabsetPanel` needs an `id` in order to be able to reference it with the inputs.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textOutput("panel")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabset",
        tabPanel("panel 1", "one"),
        tabPanel("panel 2", "two"),
        tabPanel("panel 3", "three")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$panel <- renderText({
    paste("Current panel: ", input$tabset)
  })
}
```

Based on your description, you would have empty `tabPanel` entries.

Comment: is it possible to do something like output$pl_list[[tid]] - where the pl_list is a list of plots and the tid is the id of the generated tab/ a counter

Comment: If those variable (output or not) are accessible, I don't see why not. Hard to tell without concrete examples and/or experimenting though.

Comment: I posted the code as an answer (sorry for not posting it properly)

Comment: forgot to send this too, these are the necessary files to be loaded/uploaded in the app: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bcGyE42aD5gicmdZseRGqvfT-Iu9FHLP?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry to be a bit rude, but this is not really the way to use stackoverflow. Your original question was already too convoluted (hence someone's downvote) and my answer seems to be answering the "essence of it": yes it is possible to update shiny elements based on selected tabs. 

If you have more specific problems, please provide a minimal runnable example (smallest code possible, no/minimum external dependencies, etc), then others can help. 

Long convoluted questions with complex examples required way too much effort to UNDERSTAND it, and very small chance to answer it correctly.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'm new to posting here, sorry for not explaining properly, it's also different with the way one person understands, I've explained the problem to someone else who understood and are currently trying to fix it. The example above is runnable with the files I've sent. The main problem is in the observe function and the appendTab one where plotOutput(pl_list[tid]) and output$pl_list[[x]] <- renderPlot(pl_list[[x]]) are. Everything else works.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(ggtext)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
library(bslib)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tools)

tid <<- 0 
data_list <<- list()
pl_list <<- list()
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("text"),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
              tabPanel(
                title = "Home",
                value = "home",
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    h3("Generate plots"),
                    fileInput("probe1", "Metadata .XLSX File", accept = "xlsx", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
                    fileInput("probe2", "Otu_counts (subsample.shared) .TSV File", accept = "tsv", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
                    fileInput("probe3", "Taxonomy .TSV File", accept = "tsv", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
                    textInput("caption", "Name of the plot", "Example: plot1"),
                    verbatimTextOutput("value"),
                    actionButton("add", "Add", icon = icon("plus-circle"))
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    helpText("Description:"),
                    helpText("The required tables need to have information about:...")
                  )
                )
              ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyInput <- function(name, id) paste(name, id, sep = "_")
  rv <- reactiveValues(counter = 0L)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    rv$counter <- rv$counter + 1L
    ## GO TO THE NEWLY CREATED TAB:
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", shinyInput("new_tab", rv$counter))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    tid <<- tid + 1
    #p_name <<- p('plot', tid)
    inputs <- reactiveValues(input1 = input$probe1, input2 = input$probe2, input3 = input$probe3)
    print(inputs)
    print(paste0("This is input1: ", inputs$input1))
    #data_list <<- append(data_list,
    metadata <- read_excel(inputs$input1$datapath, na="NA") %>%
      select(sample_id, disease_stat) %>%
      drop_na(disease_stat)
    
    otu_counts <- read_tsv(inputs$input2$datapath) %>%
      select(Group, starts_with("Otu")) %>%
      rename(sample_id = Group) %>%
      pivot_longer(-sample_id, names_to="otu", values_to = "count")
    
    taxonomy <- read_tsv(inputs$input3$datapath) %>%
      select("OTU", "Taxonomy") %>%
      rename_all(tolower) %>%
      mutate(taxonomy = str_replace_all(taxonomy, "\\(\\d+\\)", ""),
             taxonomy = str_replace(taxonomy, ";$", "")) %>%
      separate(taxonomy,
               into=c("kingdom", "phylum", "class", "order", "family", "genus"),
               sep=";")
    
    otu_rel_abund <- inner_join(metadata, otu_counts, by="sample_id") %>%
      inner_join(., taxonomy, by="otu") %>%
      group_by(sample_id) %>%
      mutate(rel_abund = count / sum(count)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-count) %>%
      pivot_longer(c("kingdom", "phylum", "class", "order", "family", "genus", "otu"),
                   names_to="level",
                   values_to="taxon") %>%
      mutate(disease_stat = factor(disease_stat,
                                   levels=c("NonDiarrhealControl",
                                            "DiarrhealControl",
                                            "Case")))
    
    taxon_rel_abund <- otu_rel_abund %>%
      filter(level=="phylum") %>%
      group_by(disease_stat, sample_id, taxon) %>%
      summarize(rel_abund = sum(rel_abund), .groups="drop") %>%
      group_by(disease_stat, taxon) %>%
      summarize(mean_rel_abund = 100*mean(rel_abund), .groups="drop") %>%
      mutate(taxon = str_replace(taxon,
                                 "(.*)_unclassified", "Unclassified *\\1*"),
             taxon = str_replace(taxon,
                                 "^(\\S*)$", "*\\1*"))
    
    taxon_pool <- taxon_rel_abund %>%
      group_by(taxon) %>%
      summarize(pool = max(mean_rel_abund) < 3, 
                mean = mean(mean_rel_abund),
                .groups="drop")
    
    df <- inner_join(taxon_rel_abund, taxon_pool, by="taxon") %>%
      mutate(taxon = if_else(pool, "Other", taxon)) %>%
      group_by(disease_stat, taxon) %>%
      summarize(mean_rel_abund = sum(mean_rel_abund),
                mean = min(mean),
                .groups="drop") %>%
      mutate(taxon = factor(taxon),
             taxon = fct_reorder(taxon, mean, .desc=TRUE),
             taxon = fct_shift(taxon, n=1))
    print(c(df))
    #print(df$taxon)
    dff <<- as.data.frame(df)
    data_list[[tid]] <<- dff
    
    # pl_list[[tid]] <<- ggplot(data_list[[tid]], aes(x="", y=mean_rel_abund, fill=taxon)) +
    #   geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
    #   # facet_grid(.~ data2()$disease_stat)+F
    #   theme_classic() +
    #   theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
    #         axis.text = element_blank(),
    #         axis.ticks = element_blank())
    
    print(paste("Before append:", data_list[[tid]]$disease_stat ))
    #output$plot <- render....
    
    appendTab(inputId = "tabs", tabPanel(title = input$caption, value = tid, 
                                         headerPanel('Microbiome'),
                                         mainPanel(
                                           plotOutput(pl_list[tid]),
                                           selectInput(inputId = shinyInput("case", rv$counter), label = strong("Case"),
                                                       choices = unique(data_list[[tid]]$disease_stat),
                                                       selected = "DiarrhealControl")
                                         ),
                                         
                                         actionButton(shinyInput("remove_btn", rv$counter), "Remove", icon = icon("minus-circle"))
                                         
    )) 
    
    
    print(paste("After append", data_list[[tid]]$disease_stat))
    ##########################
    print(inputs)
    
  })
  
  ## REACTIVITY TO ARRANGE TAB NAMES:
  current.tab <- eventReactive(input$tabs, {
    # don't accidentally remove main tab:
    if (!identical(input$tabs, "home")) {
      input$tabs
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (rv$counter > 0L) {
      lapply(seq(rv$counter), function(x) {
        observeEvent(input[[paste("case", x, sep = "_")]], {
          dfg <- filter(data_list[[tid]], disease_stat == input[[paste("case", x, sep = "_")]])
          print(paste("this is dfg disease_stat:", dfg$disease_stat))
          v2 <- rainbow(length(dfg$taxon))
          names(v2) <- unique(dfg$taxon)
          print(length(names(v2)))
          print(paste(dfg$taxon, " ", round(dfg$mean_rel_abund, 1),"%"))
          if (length(names(v2)) == 1)
          {
            # v2["Other"] = "#FFFFFF"
          }
          else
          {
            v2["Other"] = "#808080"
          }
          pl_list[[x]] <<- ggplot(dfg, aes(x="", y=mean_rel_abund, fill=taxon)) +
            geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
            scale_fill_manual(values = v2, labels=paste(gsub('\\*', '', dfg$taxon), str_replace_all(paste(round(dfg$mean_rel_abund, 1),"%"), " ", "")))+
            # facet_grid(.~ data2()$disease_stat)+
            theme_classic() +
            theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks = element_blank())
          output$pl_list[[x]] <- renderPlot(pl_list[[x]])
        })
      })
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (rv$counter > 0L) {
      lapply(seq(rv$counter), function(x) {
        observeEvent(input[[paste("remove_btn", x, sep = "_")]], {
          print(paste0("This is x: ",x))
          removeTab(inputId = "tabs", target = current.tab())
          print(paste0("Removing: ", input[[paste("remove_btn", x, sep = "_")]]))
        })
      })
    }
  })
  
  
  output$text <- renderText({paste0("You are viewing tab \"", input$tabs, "\"", " Rv$counter is: ", rv$counter)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```